# How to run Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration from PSGitLab 2.7.0

Tags: gitlab-api

I'm trying to use this package to automate some GitLab processes with PowerShell. 
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSGitLab/2.7.0

For my first test, I just ran this: 
Get-GitLabUser -ID "myuser"

and got this output; then tried to run Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration, but not sure what I'm supposed to enter for "Token" nor "Domain".  I tried the domain I log with, and the URL of the GitLab website that I use; but it says it doesn't match the RegEx pattern.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The info for the tokens is here: I found the token info here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html

Rather than looking online for doc, I should have run the get-help commands:

BizTalk:\Applications> ***get-help Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration -examples***

NAME
    Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration

SYNOPSIS
    Used to store information about your GitLab instance.

```
-------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration -Domain http://gitlab.com -Token "mPnTssWyBCMjxxxxxxxJQ"
```

BizTalk:\Applications> ***get-help Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration -detailed***

NAME
    Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration

SYNOPSIS
    Used to store information about your GitLab instance.

SYNTAX
    Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration [-Token]  [-Domain]  [-APIVersion ] []

DESCRIPTION
    Used to store information about your GitLab instance. The domain and api token are given.

PARAMETERS
    -APIVersion 
        The version of API used to execute calls.

```
-Domain <Object>
    The domain your GitLab instance runs under. Example: http://gitlab.com.

-Token <Object>
    Your private token that can be found under the profile settings.

<CommonParameters>
    This cmdlet supports the common parameters: Verbose, Debug,
    ErrorAction, ErrorVariable, WarningAction, WarningVariable,
    OutBuffer, PipelineVariable, and OutVariable. For more information, see 
    about_CommonParameters (http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113216). 

-------------------------- EXAMPLE 1 --------------------------

Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration -Domain http://gitlab.com -Token "mPnTssWyBCMjxxxxxxxJQ"
```

REMARKS
    To see the examples, type: "get-help Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration -examples".
    For more information, type: "get-help Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration -detailed".
    For technical information, type: "get-help Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration -full".
    For online help, type: "get-help Save-GitLabAPIConfiguration -online"

When I put http: on the domain it worked.  Seems like they really want a URL, not a domain.